# Upgrade HDD to SSD for ROG Strix G531GU

Tags: laptop, gaming, ssd

I have had some problems with my laptop recently, and I wanted to change the current hard disk drive. On task manager, the hard disk drive is labelled as ST1000LX015-1U7172. From Googling, I understand that this is a 2.5 inch SATA Internal SSHD Hard Drive with 7 mm Form Factor. I am looking to replace this with an SSD.

I was worried about compatibility, and I just wanted to ask for advice on here as to whether what these SSDs may fit in place of the current HDD, and if you have any recommendations.

- [Bliksem SSD 1TB SATA III internal Solid State Drive 2.5″ 7mm(0.28″)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B09WDHQ1Y5)
- [Crucial BX500 1TB 3D NAND SATA 2.5 Inch Internal SSD](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07YD579WM)
- [Samsung EVO 1TB SATA 2.5" Internal Solid State Drive](https://www.ebuyer.com/1139123)

My laptop is a [ROG Strix G531GU](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Asus-ROG-Strix-G531GU-AL018.444491.0.html) for context. Thank you!

Comment: Bliksem is Dutch for lightning, but I wouldn't trust putting any lightning in my computer

Comment: Crucial is also a rock solid reliable brand FWIW. I don't agree that "anything" Samsung puts out is a good choice; They have had some bad firmware issues over the years that led to customers losing data. Do your research for stuff like this when you've narrowed it down to a model number. You might even find this is true for Crucial too but I personally can't recall any wide-spread issues on their SSDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That Crucial and Samsung SSD are fine, although I personally have preference on the Crucial MX500. Here in Belgium it's pretty cheap, it will fit on any spot where there used to be a SATA HDD, and is availible in capacities between 250GB and 4TB. It also has a DRAM cache which makes it so things slow down less under heavy load. Although the price has increased lately, it's still an okay price since it's high quality (€80 for the 1TB model)